# How to find in ddms tool in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

android studio in where DDMS and Android Monitor Device tools show?
tools>Android>Android Monitor Device

[image: Screenshot from Android Studio]

Answer (score 0):

DDMS is deprecated. Instead you can use [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)